# AD FS using Chilkat

Tags: adfs, chilkat, chilkat-email

I have customers using my application that want to use AD FS to retrieve e-mails from there accounts like GMAIL. Can i use Chilkat to retrieve the e-mails from AD FS accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but probably not in the way you intend.

ADFS is a mechanism for [managing user entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/the-role-of-claims) in a Microsoft system.  G Suite has an integration that can read and provision users based on their ADFS entitlements, as well as enable [SSO using a SAML-like system](https://araihan.wordpress.com/2017/09/21/adfs-4-0-step-by-step-guide-federating-with-google-apps/).

You can use any software to access a G Suite account, but you probably won't be able to easily use the SSO infrastructure provided by the ADFS integration to authenticate.

Instead, you'll want to use the [OAuth entitlement system](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) baked into G Suite.  This would allow users to grant access (authenticated in whatever way is configured by their organization) to access their email with your application that accesses their G Suite email using the [GMail APIs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).

The benefit of this approach is that you actually broaden your customer base because your application can be used on ANY gmail or gsuite account, not just accounts that use ADFS.